# read text file in python and give them different names according to line

Tags: python

I have a folder with text files formatted like so:

```
Weather forecast
London
Monday, 1
Tuesday, 2
Wednesday, 3
Thursday, 4
Friday, 5
```

The first line of the file is the title; the second line is a sub-title; the rest of the file is a list of values, one per line.

I have been asked to write a function named `read_file` to return (title, subtitle, data_list), in this format:

```
'Weather forecast'
'London'
['Monday, 1\n', 'Tuesday, 2\n', 'Wednesday, 3\n', 'Thursday, 4\n', 'Friday, 5']
```

Comment: `with open(file_name, 'w') as f:` That 'w' stands for "write". You want `r` for "read".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to fix your post to ask the question more clearly and directly, as described in [ask] - this is *not a discussion forum*, so we don't care about things like your level of experience (and we can tell anyway, from the nature of the problem). That said, "I don't know where to start, please help me" [is not actionable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: You should start by trying to use your code and see what happens, and how that is different from what is supposed to happen. Then you should try to fix it, following a [methodical procedure](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) anything that confuses you along the way. Stack Overflow is a last resort. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 for specific guidance on homework questions.

Comment: Start by trying to think about the problem analytically. What are the logical steps that you need to follow? After opening the file - then what? Do you handle each line of the file the same way, or are some of them special in some way? Also, given that your code needs to create a list in the output, what process do you think would be appropriate for that?

Comment: You should also make sure that you understand what `return` and `print` do, and that they are *completely unrelated*. You should make sure of whether the assignment says to return values or to display (print) them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        title, subtitle, *lines = file.readlines()
        print(f"'{title[:-2]}'")
        print(f"'{subtitle[:-2]}'")
        print(lines)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! this method works well, however the first two lines returned aren't included in a quotation mark, to indicate they are strings. Is there anyway I can make that happen? Many thanks

Comment: Do you need to print them together with quotes?

Comment: Not together, the title and subtitle should just be the same as the txt file format, but in ''.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer. See it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it

```
lines = []
with open('scratch_10.txt') as f:
    title, subtitle, *rem = f.readlines()
    lines.append(title)
    lines.append(subtitle)
    lines.append(rem)

print(lines)
```

Comment: Ahh.. It seems, there is already an answer similar to mine.